# Strangeness with DataContext and GridView / ListView

Tags: data-binding, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a Windows 8 store app based off of the grouped template project, with some renames etc. However, I'm having a hard time getting the ItemsSource databinding to work for *both* non-snapped and snapped visual states.

I have a property, that, when set, changes the ItemsSource property, but I can only get one of the controls to bind at a time (either the GridView for non-snapped, or the ListView for snapped).

When I use the following, only the non-snapped binding works and the snapped binding shows no items:

```
protected PickLeafModel ListViewModel
{
  get
  {
    return (PickLeafModel)m_itemGridView.ItemsSource;
  }

  set
  {
    m_itemGridView.ItemsSource = value;
    m_snappedListView.ItemsSource = value;
  }
}
```

If I comment out one of the setters, the snapped view shows items but the non-snapped view shows nothing:

```
protected PickLeafModel ListViewModel
{
  get
  {
    return (PickLeafModel)m_itemGridView.ItemsSource;
  }

  set
  {
    //m_itemGridView.ItemsSource = value;
    m_snappedListView.ItemsSource = value;
  }
}
```

It's as if I can bind my view model only to one property at a time. What am I doing wrong?

Since I am generating my data model on another thread (yes, using the thread pool), I cannot make it inherit from DependencyObject. If I do, I get a WrongThreadException.

So to make it work I have done the following:

```
public class PickLeafModel : IEnumerable
{
  public PickLeafModel()
  {
  }

  public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
  {
    if (m_enumerator == null)
    {
      m_enumerator = new PickLeafModelViewDataEnumerator(m_data, m_parentLeaf);
    }

    return m_enumerator;
  }

  private SerializableLinkedList<PickLeaf> m_data = 
    new SerializableLinkedList<PickLeaf>();
}
```

and then my items look like this:

```
  // Augments pick leafs by returning them wrapped with PickLeafViewData.
  class PickLeafModelViewDataEnumerator : IEnumerator
  {
    public PickLeafModelViewDataEnumerator(
      SerializableLinkedList<PickLeaf> data, PickLeaf parentLeaf)
    {
      m_viewDataList =
        new System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<PickLeafViewData>();

      foreach (PickLeaf leaf in data)
      {
        PickLeafViewData viewData = new PickLeafViewData();
        viewData.copyFromPickLeaf(leaf, parentLeaf);
        m_viewDataList.AddLast(viewData);
      }

      m_enumerator = m_viewDataList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      m_viewDataList = null;
      m_enumerator = null;
    }

    public object Current
    {
      get
      {
        return m_enumerator.Current;
      }
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
      return m_enumerator.MoveNext();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
      m_enumerator.Reset();
    }

    private IEnumerator<PickLeafViewData> m_enumerator = null;

    private System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<PickLeafViewData>
      m_viewDataList;
  }
}
```

Is there something I'm doing fundamentally wrong?

Help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ross for pointing me in the right direction.

I'm not 100% happy with this solution, but it does work. Basically the idea is that after I get back the PickLeafModel from the worker threads, I transplant its internal data into a derived version of the class which is data binding aware.

```
public class PickLeafViewModel : PickLeafModel, IEnumerable
{
  public PickLeafViewModel()
  {
  }

  public PickLeafViewModel(PickLeafModel model)
  {
    SetData(model);
  }

  public void SetData(PickLeafModel model)
  {
    model.swap(this);
  }

  public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
  {
    if (m_observableData == null)
    {
      m_observableData = new ObservableCollection<PickLeafViewData>();

      var data = getData();
      PickLeaf parentLeaf = getParentLeaf();
      foreach (PickLeaf leaf in data)
      {
        PickLeafViewData viewData = new PickLeafViewData();
        viewData.copyFromPickLeaf(leaf, parentLeaf);
        m_observableData.Add(viewData);
      }
    }

    return m_observableData.GetEnumerator();
  }
```

and the page code is as follows:

```
protected PickLeafViewModel ListViewModel
{
  get
  {
    return DataContext as PickLeafViewModel;
  }

  set
  {
    DataContext = value;
  }
}
```

whenever I want to set ListViewModel, I can do this:

```
  ListViewModel = new PickLeafViewModel(model);
```

and swap looks like:

```
private static void swap<T>(ref T lhs, ref T rhs)
{
  T temp;
  temp = lhs;
  lhs = rhs;
  rhs = temp;
}

// Swaps internals with the other model.
public void swap(PickLeafModel other)
{
  swap(ref m_data, ref other.m_data);
  ...
```

Also, PickLeafModelViewDataEnumerator can be deleted altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully there is a much easier way to do what you are trying!

Create a class called your ViewModel as shown below:

```
public class DataViewModel
{
    public DataViewModel()
    {
        Data = new ObservableCollection<PickLeafViewData>(new PickLeafModelViewDataEnumerator(m_data, m_parentLeaf));             
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PickLeafViewData> Data
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

Now on the code behind set the Page.DataConected to equal an instance of the above class.

And finally on both your snapped listview, and the grid view set the item source to this:-

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
```

That should work nicely for you.

Comment: Thanks Ross for the answer. Unfortunately it does not work "out of the box" (complains that I need an IEnumerable not an IEnumerator). It is also too convoluted for me to understand exactly what your solution is trying to do. Can you please explain?